# Como colocar cursor:move em uma div draggable com javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de uma `div`

```
<div class="teste" draggable="true">CONTEÚDO DA DIV</div>
```

Eu gostaria de que quando eu arrastasse esta `div` pela tela o cursor ficasse em default, mas o problema é que só com CSS eu não consigo pois o cursor fica como se estivesse bloqueado! e tbm eu desenvolvi o código em `jQuery`, sem o `UI`, portanto não tenho acesso à funções como `draggable()`

Answer (score 3):

Não existe API para mudar o `cursor` de um elemento que está em `drag` com HTML5.
Talvez isso venha a ser possível com a futura versão [CSS4 com os pseudo-seletores para drag](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#drag-pseudos)...

Se queres controlar o `cursor` tens de fazer o `drag` com JavaScript "antigo" mudando a posição do elemento com as coordenadas do evento.

Para estes casos, a imagem do cursor pode ser mudada com CSS assim:

```
cursor: nome-do-tipo-de-cursor;
```

e as opções são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para forçar um estilo podes ainda usar o `!important;`